# How to create manually create my own ᴏᴛᴀ update file to be used for adb sideload?

Tags: rooting, root-access, 9.0-pie, ota-update, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-3

In my case, I don’t want to permanently root my own device and if possible, I want to modify the `/data` partition directly.

In order to do so, I want to add a single file to the /system partition or even apply capabilities on a single executable. That means no apk ; no new apps ; no bootloader changes.

But everything I found for creating my own ota for rooting explains how to use adb to apply it, not how to build such a file myself. Or suppose that I’m building for a firmware I designed myself for which I have the signing keys (whereas the aim is to do it for stock Samsung).

So **how to create my own file‑based** (with the aim to modify file permissions to existing files) **ota zip file which can be installed through adb sideload on all devices as SuperSu does** ?

Comment: If you you are targeting a stock rom and you know that the requirement is that you have access to the signing keys the system was signed with (which you don't have) why do you ask here? What do you expect from us if the task is impossible?

Comment: @Robert with oem unlocking, signing is only relevant for building the package. I want to create the same kind of package as SuperSu (The version of superSu which you can install as an ᴏᴛᴀ update).

Comment: I would consider OEM unlocking as a bootloader modification as it changes the bootloader configuration.

Comment: @Robert with samsung galaxy tab S3, this is something which is done from System Settings not related to the warrent or Safety Net.

Comment: Usually in system settings you can only allow OEM unlocking. The actual unlocking process has to be started by certain commands sent to the bootloader afterwards.

Comment: @Robert in that case this is the only thing to be done as nothing else is required.

Comment: Are you really sure? That would violate security requirements by Google as it would allow to unlock a bootloader without deleting the user data. If this is true it would be another reason to never by a Samsung device.

Comment: @Robert I just changed my device to the stock firmware of another region this afternoon that way. But with Samsung, you don’t have things like Gmail becoming the only way to use other e‑mail ɪᴍᴀᴘ boxes (but I don’t know how to modify it).

Comment: Hello @user2284570. Please mention what kind of OTA you  are targeting? Whether flashable through a recovery or via a system app (as is the case in A/B partitions supported devices)? Second, do explicitly mention whether your device has custom recovery or not, because stock recovery wouldn't permit non-OEM payload to be flashed. Third, you need to start from basics. OTA updates flashable via recovery mode are nothing more any other recovery flashable ZIP files. So start learning how to make a recovery flashable zip and then learn to modify it gradually to suit your needs.

Comment: @Firelord I said stock adb sideload. The ᴀᴅʙ command. I said this is for rooting so it implies plain stock firmware. In the SuperSu package, I saw there are hash xml files and signatures. I don’t understand the format but it seems dedicated to ᴏᴛᴀ.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my words or I didn't write clearly. Let me try again. I know what `adb sideload XYZ.zip` does. It sideloads a ZIP. The commans works on both stock recovery and custom recoveries. The ZIPs that can be sideloaded can be done using both custom and stock recoveries. But that wasn't my question so I am not getting why you replied that as an answer.

Comment: @user2284570 sir you have some gross misunderstanding with the working of bootloader and OTA updates as other experienced members are suggesting. There exists no such SuperSU `.zip` file which can be flashed to all devices with locked bootloaders and which also modifies `/system` partition without breaking `dm-verity` or any other security mechanisms based on signing keys. Official block-based OTA updates are binary patches created from the difference of old and new signed `system.img`, `vendor.img` etc. Or is your device older than Lollipop which does file-OTAs without supporting `dm-verity`?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I was talking about [that file](http://downloadmirror.co/1Kut/SR4-SuperSU-v2.78-SR4-20161115184928.zip). Though me I want something lighter ; I don’t want to get root through adding any files but to `setcap` existing executables.

Comment: @user2284570 alright. So where is it documented or how did you get the notion that this CF Auto Root flashable zip modifies files in `/system` without unlocking bootloader or without damaging `dm-verity`? // Secondly by setting file capabilities what's the final thing you want to achieve? XY problem can only be avoided by stating the actual problem.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I don’t understand you myself at that point. For raw flashing Samsung doesn’t use fastboot but Odin or Heimdall (Heimdall being the opensource clone of Odin which doesn’t have the restriction of erasing UserData after successful flash). This how oem unlocking is enough to modify `/system` since you flash directly straight after reboot and without root. [The zip file isn’t realted with ᴄꜰ auto root and is to be loaded through adb sideload](http://downloadmirror.co/1Kut/SR4-SuperSU-v2.78-SR4-20161115184928.zip).

Comment: and this zip does pass sideload on your s3? on mine it doesn't

Comment: @user2284570 instead of blindly arguing and paying no heed to what others are saying, it'd be better if you open that zip file and see its contents, particularly what the `update-binary` shell script does. It's exactly the same zip file (even hashes are same) still available at CF-Root's official website: https://download.chainfire.eu/1013/SuperSU/SR4-SuperSU-v2.78-SR4-20161115184928.zip though the project was superseded by https://desktop.firmware.mobi back in 2017. And that too along with its sister SuperSU is almost an abandoned project. So please stop playing puzzles and do some research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create or modify OTA zip without the proper OEM signing key. However, there exist holes in older devices like Samsung Galaxy Y which allow flashing unofficial zip with test keys, but these kind of hacks are outdated ([source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/development-derivatives/15-11-2012-philz-touch-3-00-cwm-based-t1840223?goto=newpost))

if you want to create OTA zip you need update-binary for your device and write updater-script in [EDIFY](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/inside_packages.html) language

you can also replace update-binary with [shell script](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=56621519&postcount=1) which makes things easier and device independent

learn how to sign your zip (scroll down to [Zip Signing](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=56621542&postcount=2))

Comment: Doesn’t seems realistic… How does SuperSu is able to produce an ᴏᴛᴀ update which can be installed over all devices through ᴀᴅʙ sideload ?

Comment: And I suppose that leaked key isn’t public ? I mean not available for the general public to sign their own ᴏᴛᴀ ?

Comment: The problem remains on how to build such file‑based zip packages. How to get the difference file to compare with ?