# Recover data on Samsung galaxy s4 mini with broken screen

Tags: data-recovery

I have broken the screen of my Samsung Galaxy S4 mini.

Nothing can be displayed and I can't touch anything.

I would like to recover data (at least contact and photos) but I don't find a way to do this.

I can't connect it via usb, it isn't recognized by the system (Mac or Windows)

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable ADB and/or change USB connection mode on Galaxy S7 w/ broken screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/enable-adb-and-or-change-usb-connection-mode-on-galaxy-s7-w-broken-screen)

Comment: I have tried but no :(

Comment: you can root the device and flash a modified system with adb root enabled (or some init.d script which places the RSA-key from MicroSD Card into data partition, if required) someone needs to guide you through [cf-auto-root](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu) and [inception](https://github.com/tgalal/inception)

Comment:  any success?

Comment: No I can't detect the phone with usb cable. I think it's not just the screen that's broken.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMoVqoVuPns

Comment: [CWM recovery](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2608083) can be installed from MicroSD card. with this you can create a backup. it can be done all from volume keys. only problem, you must do it blind. i recommend to buy another device for test (if backup fails you still can use it for spare parts to replace display)

Comment: as you can see in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prStuxMFQLM) the desired entry *'apply update from external storage'* is right above the unwanted *'wipe data/factory reset'* option. consider that timing and count of input key sequence is important. (Note: you need a [signed](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/development-derivatives/15-11-2012-philz-touch-3-00-cwm-based-t1840223?goto=newpost) variant of [update.zip](https://mega.nz/folder/oZ1QDDbC#Ko20UNhowwIlXLVFjJsyKw/file/4dsgBQLJ)) see https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222262