# Update.zip signing- different sha for the same file

Tags: rom-update

I am trying to flash a customized update.zip on a pre-Kitkat device.

In the zip there are 2 files with SHA1 signatures of other files in the update. But they have different signatures for the same files.

Example:

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Name: system/lib/libcustom_jni.so
SHA1-Digest: +PhV5XphkQTNTyM2TSRTeiaDlCA=
```

META-INF/CERT.SF:

```
Name: system/lib/libcustom_jni.so
SHA1-Digest: 7ooFhqk1oYWF5pmVuSAhF2pFVNw=
```

I can get the first one using:

```
sha1sum system/lib/libcustom_jni.so | cut -d\  -f1 | xxd -p -r | base64
+PhV5XphkQTNTyM2TSRTeiaDlCA=
```

How is the second one computed? The second file has a hash of the first file, so maybe the other hashes are salted with the first file or something?

From what i found in [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Signature_Validation) the SHAs should be identical, except all SHAs are the version 1 in the original update.zip.

It seems hat the certificate used to sign the update was the android test one so it should work, but aborts instead.

Comment: This answers my question if it is true, need to test it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9384919/1333247

Comment: it seems you have more knowledge than me, kindly check my answer and feel free to correct (or post own answer) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222262

Comment: @alecxs Thanks, but i only really played with a single Android 4.2 device so far. That question is about Android 9, i think too many things have changed between them for me to be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9384919/1333247) as i wrote in the comment. The second hash is a SHA1 of the 3 lines in the manifest file.

I can obtain the second hash by running:

```
echo 'Name: system/lib/libcustom_jni.so\r\nSHA1-Digest: +PhV5XphkQTNTyM2TSRTeiaDlCA=\r\n\r' | sha1sum | cut -d\  -f1 | xxd -p -r | base64 
7ooFhqk1oYWF5pmVuSAhF2pFVNw=
```

The echo command adds the final \n so it must be removed from the command to not be duplicated.

**Edit** for posteriority:

The update.zip is then signed by SignApk using the `-w` argument, which makes it generate a ZIP comment, without which the installation fails.
The comment consists of `signed by SignApk` string followed by a signature block. Code at [Android SignApk source](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=android_build/tools/signapk/SignApk.java#signWholeOutputFile-byte-zipData-OutputStream-outputStream-X509Certificate-publicKey-PrivateKey-privateKey)

This was the last piece of the puzzle that allowed me to create a custom update.zip for my Prestigio tablet.