# Apply update from ADB: how to use it when you are locked out of the device

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, lock-screens, locked-out, side-loading

My cousin's kid has played with his Samsung A8 (2018) phone and has changed his unlock pattern. So, nobody knows the pattern the child has set.

- The phone has no Google account set up
- The USB debugging is *not* activated on device before

I have rebooted into recovery mode, and entered the option `Apply update from ADB`:

[image: Recovery screen]

There is a message on recovery screen saying:

> Now send the package you want to apply
> to the device with `adb sideload <filename>` ...

I'm able to see the device by `adb devices` command:

[image: Command line screenshot]

According to [another post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/197443/202005), looks like it is possible to use [TWRP for Samsung Galaxy A8 2018](https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxya82018.html) to clear the screen lock. So, I have downloaded the following `apk` package:

[image: TWRP for Samsung Galaxy A8 2018]

Now I plan to install TWRP on phone by the following command and then follow the [previous post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/197443/202005):

```
adb sideload me.twrp.twrpapp-26.apk
```

#### Questions

Now, before doing so, I have these questions:

- Is it possible to install `*.apk` packages by `adb sideload`? Is there any possibility that it would mess up the phone?
- What else can I do with `adb sideload` to clear the screen lock?
- What else can be done with `adb sideload` to back up the phone camera images and videos without wiping the data?

Thanks =)

Comment: 1. What you got is the TWRP management app not the TWRP recovery, using this app you can install TWRP on a rooted device if you boot the device and start the app. 2. adb sideload is for sideloading firmware/ROM updates/full images. As far as I know you can't install APK files via sideloading at least not directly. What you should do: Perform a factory reset.

Comment: give the phone back to the childs and let keep some days, sometimes they just remember when not stressed and relaxed playing with things. in fact, that's the only option (much better chance than automatized [bruteforce](https://youtube.com/watch?v=VjZza9fNkvk) attack)

Comment: you can do nothing to by-pass security with sideload https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222262

Comment: read the [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-a8-2018/samsung-galaxy-a8-2018-roms-kernels-recoveries--other-development/recovery-twrp-3-2-2-0-galaxy-a8-2018-t3818201) support thread on xda. it's not even possible to decrypt, and hard enough to get a working TWRP flashed due some additional bootloader locks. furthermore it's a exynos chipset you can't use qualcomm [EDL](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/05/demystifying-android-physical-acquisition) tools to dump or flash something on low level. that's a dead end

Comment: Is there a way to sideload an image that would unlock the phone? I understand that for security purposes they might want to avoid this, but it would be a really helpful loophole for those of us locked out who neglected to enable usb debugging.

Comment: Is the data on the flash memory plain or encrypted? If I were to do something crazy like this https://flashfixers.com/recover-data-dead-phone-chip-off-data-recovery/, could the data be recovered?

Comment: @PavelKomarov I think the phone is factory-reset by now! Thanks =)

Comment: @PavelKomarov I studied the link. It was interesting. Thanks :)