# Samsung Galaxy unlocking software

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, locked-out

This is a followup question for [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230996/202005) and [that one](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230999/202005). Currently I'm trying [iMyFone](https://android.imyfone.com/remove-phone-lock/) software to remove the screen lock for my cousin's Samsung Galaxy A8. The problem is Galaxy A8 is *not* among the options available:

[image: Device name options screenshot]

Sometimes, devices are categorized in compatible families. I wonder if any of the listed devices above is compatible enough with Galaxy A8. Which device I can possibly choose to safely try to unlock Galaxy A8?

### UPDATE

Downloaded and installed [Dr.Fone](https://drfone.wondershare.net/android-data-recovery.html), but seems like it has the same device list.

Comment: I know, the listed devices are all old ones. But I just thought they might be compatible with Galaxy A8 ...

Comment: please forget all of these wonderful software, nothing can work on recent devices. use official methods like [find my mobile](https://findmymobile.samsung.com) or [find my device](https://google.com/android/devicemanager)

Comment: if you want to preserve userdata [this](https://youtu.be/rTnGg0XEWPM) is the only (inofficial) 'working' method but is very time consuming

Comment: i don't know why xda-developers is promoting iMyFone (probably because it's a sponsor) but this software looks like a scam. it claims to work on android 10 which can't be true. due the fact the login credentials are part of encryption, this would destroy all data (even in case it would be possible to erase screenlock)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Scams/comments/j9xazm/you_cant_cancel_your_imyfone_subscription_nor

Comment: @alecxs Thanks! Uninstalled iMyFone! =)