# How to create OTA zip and update OTA zip file into target device (android11)

Tags: ota-update, android-11, aosp

I am working on Android 11.

Cloned & compiled source code , all images are generated.

Now I am trying to generate OTA zip file and update into target device.

Can you please help me to generate OTA zip(Major & Minor) file and update procedure or steps for Android 11.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create manually create my own OTA update file to be used for adb sideload?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222262)

Comment: May I know the command to create OTA ZIP in android 11.